# Github Commited changes wont show in browser

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repo linked with visual studio code and Github desktop. I have changes some files in visual studio code and have commited them when they were picked up by Github desktop. However, I have had a look at the code in my browser and the changes are not showing when I navigate to my repo.

Comment: Have you *pushed* those changes, or just *committed* them? I'd strongly recommend running through an introductory version control tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the sync button. Or, open git command and type

`git push origin master`

Change `master` according to the branch you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not pressing the sync button on the github desktop.

Answer (score 0):

did just committed? maybe you forgot to push the changes?

make sure visual studio code and github desktop are synced